# Does angularjs's angular.bind function not work in IE if supplied a native function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

From angularjs 1.3 source
Anybody know what the main if/else statement() is doing here in regards to the IE comment? I thought it was an basic error/type check - ie. if you were not supplied a function in the fn parameter - then return it as is and don't disrupt the flow of the overall program. But the comment seems to indicate more to do with IE.

**Questions:**

Does the comment mean if angular.bind is supplied with Array.prototype.slice.call as the fn. It will stop and just return the value of the fn (bc it is native function)?
If that is the case how does this work in IE?
**Is it is plain as I understand it - if native function is supplied in this angular.bind - then in IE it will not execute properly?**

```
function bind(self, fn) {
  var curryArgs = arguments.length > 2 ? sliceArgs(arguments, 2) : [];

  if (isFunction(fn) && !(fn instanceof RegExp)) {

  /* commenting out below to highlight the if/else 

    return curryArgs.length
      ? function() {
          return arguments.length
            ? fn.apply(self, curryArgs.concat(slice.call(arguments, 0)))
            : fn.apply(self, curryArgs);
        }
      : function() {
          return arguments.length
            ? fn.apply(self, arguments)
            : fn.call(self);
        };
  */
  
  } else {
    // in IE, native methods are not functions so they cannot be bound (note: they don't need to be)
    return fn;
  }
}
```

Here is the link to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L977)

Comment: This is unfortunately a very good question with an answer that is too lengthy for this format.  Effectively, `bind` is a method to set the value of `this` in function calls.  due to differences in the ways that browsers handle `this`, it needs to be set explicitly in many cases; in IE it can't be set this way, because it doesn't make sense in the context of how IE handles `this`.  try http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/ for a deep dive on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Well - IE does support bind in general according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff841995(v=vs.94).aspx ). I understand the logic of bind - I just not understanding the logic or more the exact outcome in regards to the IE native (prototype methods) or my bold question of this library function. Really i guess could be a  yes or no answer to the question. Regarding my logic.

Comment: yes, IE supports bind for functions; native methods are not functions in IE, which is why they fail the If check, and are returned without being modified.  They still run correctly, as they do not need to be altered in the first place.